# Call to undefined method Error findIdentity() in yii2

Tags: php, session, yii2, identity

I hosted my site to a new domain. when i click some links the url redirect to index page with this error.

PHP Fatal Error – `yii\base\ErrorException`

Call to undefined method `app\models\TblAccount::findIdentity()`

Is this error related with session. Please give me solution to the problem.

Comment: show your TblAcconut model please

Comment: Make sure your `app\models\TblAccount` class Extent `yii\web\User` class

Comment: `class TblAccount extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface`

Comment: look for upercase / lowercase issue of filename/path and classname!
this is always the main problem when switching from windows development and deploy it on a linux pc. Which i think could be the problem here if its working on localhost correctly.

Comment: @BHoft ...thanks for your comment...but i hosted this same for another domain earlier and its working perfect...

Comment: Please give us the model's code and the component's declaration

Answer (score 0):

From the error it looks like you don't have findIdentity() method implemented in your TblAccount class. IdentityInterface requires you to implement it - [see documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-identityinterface.html)

Show us your code so we can help more

Answer (score 0):

> This expect method FindIdentity() in your user model as following

```
public static function findIdentity($id)
{
    return static::findOne($id);
}
```